# Is it possible to create such a CSS class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I was thinking about how having a CSS class to apply to a div element which would give an outline to all descendants inside this div container, that way it would highlight all DOM elements in the web that way. Is it possible to something like that with jQuery maybe?

```
outline:1px solid red;
```

Comment: Why not just define the CSS class in a style sheet and apply it with jQuery using `addClass`?

Comment: I want to targe all the elements inside the element with the class, I don't think you can do that with pln css

Comment: you can do with CSS --> `.my-class * {outline:1px solid red;}`

Comment: that works nice, but is it possible to give different outline colors depending of the position the element appears in the DOM tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `.yourclass(orId) *{`here you can add any css you want. Anyway, consider each element display type(block inline, etc) . Notice space between .classname AND *. If you want to target only first grade childs, use .`classname > *`
You have a full list here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp